# Are the events in Riders of Justice triggered by mistaken identity and pure coincidence?

Tags: plot-explanation, riders-of-justice

The triggering event in the blacky comic Danish revenge thriller [Riders of Justice](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11655202/?ref_=ttexrv_exrv_tt) is the identification of a character from facial recognition.

The data scientist who survives the train "accident" starts to suspect it was not an accident and that it was deliberately caused to kill a witness against the leader of a biker gang who had committed many serious crimes. His team identifies the brother of the gang leader as having been on the train and he assumes he caused the train crash. There seems to be plenty of evidence this theory makes sense and it triggers the events of the movie.

But, very late in the movie, the identification turns out to be wrong. The brother wasn't even in Denmark when the accident happened and the similar looking character who was on the train has nothing to do with the gang.

A key theme of the movie is the interplay of coincidence and deliberate action. Some things can be predicted with enough data; some are mere coincidence. For most of the movie we assume we are watching events triggered deliberately.

Does the late revelation that the character who supposedly triggered the train crash was misidentified mean we should regard the entire sequence of events in the movie purely coincidental?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riders_of_Justice